# How to check paragraph adjustment using pyUNO library in Libre/Open Office?

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, uno, pyuno

The `com.sun.star.style.ParagraphProperties` service supports the property
`ParaAdjust`, that supports 5 values from `com.sun.star.style.ParagraphAdjust`
([ParagraphProperties](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/style/ParagraphProperties.html#ParaAdjust), [ParagraphAdjust](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/style/ParagraphAdjust.html)).

To set the value, one of the two methods could be used:

```
cursor.ParaAdjust = com.sun.star.style.ParagraphAdjust.RIGHT
cursor.setPropertyValue('ParaAdjust', com.sun.star.style.ParagraphAdjust.RIGHT)
```

To check the value the first try was:

```
if cursor.ParaAdjust == com.sun.star.style.ParagraphAdjust.RIGHT:
    ...
```

but didn't work.

Inspecting:

```
type(cursor.ParaAdjust)
----> <class 'int'>
type(com.sun.star.style.ParagraphAdjust.RIGHT)
----> <class 'uno.Enum'>
```

right, I've assumed that these were constants (see Note below), my fault.

Now, the `uno.Enum` class has two properties `typeName` and `value`, so I've tried:

```
if cursor.ParaAdjust == com.sun.star.style.ParagraphAdjust.RIGHT.value:
    ...
```

but didn't work, too!

Inspecting:

```
type(com.sun.star.style.ParagraphAdjust.RIGHT.value)
----> <class 'string'>
print(com.sun.star.style.ParagraphAdjust.RIGHT.value)
----> 'RIGHT'
```

---

Setting the `ParaAdjust` property and then print its actual value, I get:

```
LEFT    = 0
RIGHT   = 1
BLOCK   = 2
CENTER  = 3
STRETCH = 0
(note that STRETCH is considered as LEFT,
 a bug or something not implemented?)
```

So:

- Where are these values defined?
- How could I get thes values using the UNO API?
- Am I missing something from the official documentation?

---

**Note**:

In LibreOffice 4.0 (maybe in older versions too), you could get this values with:

```
uno.getConstantByName('com.sun.star.style.ParagraphAdjust.RIGHT')
```

from version 4.1 that doesn't work anymore (rightly, not being a constant).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to "**hanya**" from the OpenOffice Forum ([link](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=75964)), here's some python code for mapping the values of `ParagraphAdjust`:

```
def get_paragraph_adjust_values():
    ctx = uno.getComponentContext()
    tdm = ctx.getByName(
            "/singletons/com.sun.star.reflection.theTypeDescriptionManager")
    v = tdm.getByHierarchicalName("com.sun.star.style.ParagraphAdjust")
    return {name : value
            for name, value
            in zip(v.getEnumNames(), v.getEnumValues())}
```

In python 2.6, that doesn't support the comprehension syntax for dictionaries, the **dict()** function can be used instead.